# Given a string, return true if the first instance of “x” in the string is immediately followed by another “x”

Tags: python, string, boolean

Note :

- capital X's do not count as an occurrence of "x".
- if there are no "x"'s then return false

The following code is my solution, however i don't get the correct answer.

```
def triple_x(s):
    
    
    for i in (s):
        
        if i == 'x' and i+1 =='x':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

> TEST CASES:
>
> tripleX("abraxxxas") → true
>
> tripleX("xoxotrololololololoxxx") → false
>
> tripleX("softX kitty, warm kitty, xxxxx") → true
>
> tripleX("softx kitty, warm kitty, xxxxx") → false

I would be appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: The function name suggests you're actually looking for triple x's, but you're asking about double x's - is that correct?

Comment: The function is looking for the first instance of "x" in the string if the next element is "x" again your return should be True. @Grismar

Answer (score 1):

All you had to do is just do something similar to this

```
def myx(word):
    if 'xx' in word : return True
    return False
    
print(myx('xoxotrololololololoxxx')) # this will print out true s
```

Much simpler and cleaner.  hoped this resolve your question

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your code works fine but in some cases it doesn't work.

Comment: if it possible, may i know the test case?

Comment: ("xoxotrololololololoxxx"),False). / ("softx kitty, warm kitty, xxxxx"),False)

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses around `s` are superfluous. `i` runs over `s`, so it will take the value of the characters in `s`, one at a time.

As a result, `i+1` does not give you the next character in s, instead it tries to add 1 to that character of `s`, which doesn't make sense.

You can use your solution, if you have `i` range over the indexes of characters in `s`. Also, your current solutions doesn't take into account a situation like `s = "oxoxxx"` where the first `x` doesn't meet your criteria, but the second one does (in which case I assume you need the answer to be `False`)

This stays close to your solution, but works:

```
def triple_x(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == 'x':
            if i+1 < len(s) and s[i+1] =='x':
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

A shorter way of writing the same:

```
def triple_x(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == 'x':
            return i+1 < len(s) and s[i+1] =='x':
```

As the comparison returns a `bool` value.

Here's a solution that's close to optimal:

```
def triple_x(s):
    i = s.find('x')
    return i+1 != len(s) and s[i+1] == 'x'
```

Comment: Your code is work perfectly, however it doesn't work for these test cases.               
Test_case(triple_x(""), False)
Test_case(triple_x("there's no XXX here"), False)

Comment: The length check I put in the "optimal" case wasn't in the previous ones, I'd expect them to all work now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `re.search` here for a regex approach:

```py
inp_valid = "blah blah xx other text here"
if re.search(r'^[^x]*xx', inp_valid):
    print "VALID"
else:
    print "INVALID"

inp_invalid = "blah blah xtra text here"
if re.search(r'^[^x]*xx', inp_invalid):
    print "VALID"
else:
    print "INVALID"
```

This prints:

```
VALID
INVALID
```